# Как разместить элементы на одной линии html css

Tags: html, css

Хочу разместить элементы в таком порядке, т.е. все на одной линии
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждая картинка должна быть с отступами от левого/правого края на 40px от основного контента

HTML

```
<div id="block2">       
    <img src="img/smmini.png">
    <h1>Заслуженный герой<br><p>Советского союза<p></h1>
    <img src="img/smmini.png">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#block2 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 40px;
}
h1 > span {
  display: block;
}
img {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block2">
  <img src="img/smmini.png">
  <h1>Заслуженный герой 
     <span>Советского союза</span>
  </h1>
  <img src="img/smmini.png">
</div>
```